# Oracle - update json array with new element (if does not exist yet)

Tags: arrays, json, oracle

I have an Oracle / Json question... I hope someone can help.

I just discovered the JSON_TABLE functionality of Oracle and I am exploring how I could use it to store, update and recover Json data.

I can query JSON array, now I want to update an array with a value.

### Context

I have a json array (it represents a list of "day of the year"), something like this :

```
create table tmp_json (
  id         number(10) not null,
  data       clob,
  constraint pk_tmp_json primary key (id),
  constraint check_data_json check (data is json)
);

INSERT INTO tmp_json (id, data)
VALUES (3,
        '{
           "doy" : [ 7, 8, 9 ]
         }'
);
```

I can query the array with something like

```
select tmp_json.id,
       jt.*
from   tmp_json,
       json_table(data, '$'
         columns (
           nested path '$.doy[*]' columns (
             "doy" path '$' null on error
           )
         )
       ) "JT";

ID DOY
-- ---
 3 7
 3 8
 3 9
```

Great ...

### Question 1

I want to add an item to the array, say "10" if we are the 10th day of the year, say this :

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('10-01-2018'),'DDD')) doy from dual;

10
```

How can I easily update the stored json with my "10" above

### Question 2

How can I do this only if "10" does not already exist in the JSON array ?

I thank already anyone who would take some time to look at this !

Thanks !
David

Comment: Check if this helps. https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/12-things-developers-will-love-about-oracle-database-12c-release-2#json

Comment: Humm... no OOB easy way to update a table within an existing and recorded JSON string there AFAI can see. I ended up splitting up the entire JSON with json_table(...), add the new element (easy in pure sql once it is splitted up, dealing with existence with union (distinct) and rebuild the json string. I wish we could just add a JSON array element, but it does not sound possible. let's be honest, this is still great feature !